# Getting wrong answer in a rate of change problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

[image]

> In the figure, a metal ball is placed at the bottom of a spherical container with water. The radii of the container and the metal ball are $8$ cm and $4$ cm respectively. Let $h$ cm be the depth of water.

> (a) It is given that the volume of a portion of a sphere cut off by a horizontal plane is $\pi \left(rH^2 - \frac{H^3} 3 \right) \ \text{cm}^3$, where $r$ cm is the radius of the sphere and $H$ cm is the height of the portion. Show that the volume of water in the container is
> (i) $\frac{\pi}{3}(-h^3 + 24h^2 - 256) \ \text{cm}^3$ for $8 \leq h \leq 16$,
> (ii) $4\pi h^2 \ \text{cm}^3$ for $0 \leq h \lt 8$

> (b) When the container is fully filled up with water, its bottom cracks suddenly, and the water leaks at a rate of $\pi \ \text{cm}^3/s$. Find the rate of decrease of the depth of water after the container has been leaking for 6 minutes. (Give your answer correct to 3 significant figures.)

I have done (a) part but got the wrong answer in (b).   Here is how I do it:
Let V denote the volume of the sphere, $v(h)$ denotes the volume of water and $h$ denotes the depth of water,
After $6$ minutes, the volume of water is
$$\frac{4}{3} \pi 8^3 - 360 \pi = \frac{968 \pi}{3} \lt \frac{1}{2}V$$
Then find $h_0$ which is the final depth of water,
\begin{align}
4 \pi h_0^2 &= \frac{968 \pi}{3} \\
h_0 &= \sqrt{\frac{242}{3}}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} &= \frac{dv}{dh} \frac{dh}{dt} \\
-\pi &= 8 \pi h_0 \frac{dh}{dt} \\
\frac{dh}{dt} = -0.139
\end{align}

But my answer was wrong, the suggested one was $-0.0162 \ \text{cm/s}$, where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that $\frac{968 \pi}{3} > \frac{1}{2}V$. I get that $V = \frac{1792}{3} \pi$ both using the formula ($h = 16$) and calculating the volume of the large sphere - small sphere.

Comment: @TobyMak You're right. I will try this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 6 minutes, the volume of water is actually:

$$\frac{4}{3} \pi (8)^3 - 6(60) \pi - \frac{4}{3}\pi(4)^3= \frac{712 \pi}{3} \lt \frac{1}{2}V$$

because you have forgotten to subtract the volume of the steel ball.

Then repeating your steps (which are correct), $h_0 = \frac{\sqrt{534}}{3}$, and so $\frac{dh}{dt} = -\frac{1}{8h_0} = -0.0162 \ \text{cm}/\text{s}$.

Comment: What's your definition of $V$? Is it the volume of the container including the metal sphere or no?

Comment: The volume of the container *not* including the metal sphere. The metal sphere cannot be filled up with water, so I excluded it from the total volume.

Comment: Then what is the significance of the volume of water being $\lt \frac{1}{2}V$?

Comment: Should it be $V - \frac{712\pi}{3} > \text{the volume of the outer hemisphere}$?

Comment: Actually, since $h_0 = \frac{\sqrt{534}}{3} < 8$, you have to calculate $\frac{dv}{dt}$ separately for the two different rates of change, from the two formulas from the volume of water.

Comment: I suspect that the question has a logical error: you cannot use the second formula for the volume blindly as the volume of water first decreases from $h = 16$ to $h = 8$, then from $h = 8$ to $h = \sqrt{534}/3$.

Comment: Now I have a question for you: did you understand *why* you were writing down those steps, or were you writing them because they looked similar to what you did in class?

Comment: Yes, I understand what I am doing. When I wrote $\lt \frac{V}{2}$, I intended to say that the water level was below the top of the metal sphere, but it's clearly done wrong.

Comment: And I think the rate of change as the volume of water first decreases from $h = 16$ to $h = 8$ doesn't matter if what we need to know is just the rate of change when $h$ is somewhere between $8$ and $0$